# How i can fix mypy error: Incompatible types in assignment expression has type Optional

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.10

For example, i have a this code:

```py
def func(
    a: int | None = None,
    b: str | None = None,
):
    if not (a or b):
        b = "string"
    elif a:
        b = str(a)
    c: str = b
    return type(c)
```

for which the error raises:

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[str]", variable has type "str")`

Why does mypy raise an error for this case? In either case of calling `func` we can ensure that `c` is not of type `None`:

```py
assert func() == str
assert func(a=1) == str
assert func(b="2") == str
assert func(a=3, b="4") == str
```

How can I convince mypy that the code is correct without this useless block after "if" statement?

```py
    if b is None:
        raise RuntimeError
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same type for `c` in this case within `func()`:

```
def func(a: Optional[int] = None, b: Optional[str] = None):
    if not (a or b):
        b = "string"
    elif a:
        b = str(a)
    c: Optional[str] = b
    return type(c)
```

Note I used the type `Optional` from the module *typing* as it is clearer and backwards compatible with older Python versions.

Another option is to ignore this specific error (because you already have it under control):

```
c: str = b  # type: ignore
```

Comment: But my code just an example. I need exactly `str` type for `c`. You can paste 
`c = c + c`
before return for more relevant example.

Comment: That makes me think it doesn't make sense the type of argument `b`, it should be just `str` as you're never calling this function with `b=None`. Otherwise, ignore this specific error as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: As you can see in block of code with asserts, i'm calling `func` with `b=None`. It`s line 1 and line 2. 
And ignoring shouldn't be a solution for such a simple case.